# AngularJS Удаление элемента из списка таблицы

Tags: angularjs

Для удаления элемента `<tr>` из таблицы

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat='dev in device'>
    <td>{{dev.id}}</td>
    <td>{{dev.name}}</td>
    <td>{{dev.updated_at}}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="del(dev.id)">×</a></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

посоветовали такую конструкцию.

```
$scope.del= function(id) {
     let index = $scope.device.find(dev => dev.id === id);
     if (index !== -1) $scope.device.splice(index, 1);
 }
```

Ирония в том, что в таком случае удаляется первый элемент таблицы,  но никак не конкретный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, в функции `del()` нужно использовать метод `findIndex`, а не `find`.
А во-вторых, проще использовать ангуляровскую переменную $index (см. функцию `del2()`):

```js
let app = angular.module('test', [])
.controller('testCntr', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.device = [
    {id : 1, name : 'abc', updated_at : '01:00'},
    {id : 2, name : 'def', updated_at : '01:10'},
    {id : 3, name : 'ghi', updated_at : '01:20'},
    {id : 4, name : 'jkl', updated_at : '01:30'}
  ];
  $scope.del= function(id) {
    let index = $scope.device.findIndex(dev => dev.id === id);
    if (index !== -1) $scope.device.splice(index, 1);
  }
  $scope.del2 = function(index) {
    $scope.device.splice(index, 1);
  }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app='test' ng-controller='testCntr'>
    <tr ng-repeat='dev in device'>
    <td>{{dev.id}}</td>
    <td>{{dev.name}}</td>
    <td>{{dev.updated_at}}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="del(dev.id)">×</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click="del2($index)">x</a></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Всё ясно

Comment: Наверное, вы хотели написать *нужно использовать метод `findIndex`, а не `find`*.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, да, конечно, спасибо :) Исправил.